# Jenkinsfile not able to run docker

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am following this blog https://getintodevops.com/blog/building-your-first-docker-image-with-jenkins-2-guide-for-developers
1)git clone the repo -- done
2)build the image locally -- done
3)running it locally --done
4)"Build now" give following error

```
Running on Jenkins in /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_build_docker_with_jenkins
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone repository)
[Pipeline] checkout
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git
 > git init /Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_build_docker_with_jenkins # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/getintodevops/hellonode.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 2241f48e193a956e9c25706555ee3e4c9c0728c5 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 2241f48e193a956e9c25706555ee3e4c9c0728c5
Commit message: "feat: dummy test"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build image)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t getintodevops/hellonode .
/Users/mano/.jenkins/workspace/so_build_docker_with_jenkins@tmp/durable-91e2f197/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have docker installed?

Comment: I have docker installed locally on my mac .on terminal I check the which docker and it gives me the path /usr/bin/docker , also I have jenkins-global tool configuration and set a variable docker , should i be pointing to my local docker ? or should i check install automatically ? I have jenkins on my mac not a docker container running jenkins

Comment: What about your slaves (or is your master also your slave)?

Comment: Master and slave are the same

Comment: Ok, so if you are running Jenkins through docker (master and slave), then your docker container (which you are using to run Jenkins) must also have docker installed! Do you see why?

Comment: In the page you linked, under requirement 2, there is a link to another tutorial, I believe you must follow that one before moving on to the one you are doing now.

Comment: I meant I am running jenkins on my local machine not on a docker container on my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193344/discussion-between-perplexabot-and-user17970).

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all my docker and Jenkins installs and then did a clean install of Jenkins and docker and it started working for me